# Are smaller rockets easier to land?

Tags: rockets, landing, smallsat-launcher

Is it easier to land a smaller rocket compared to bigger rockets?? Since they are lighter

Comment: It truly comes down to the rocket dynamics, Yes in terms of weight a smaller rocket might be easier to land, but then again what are you referring to by "landing" if you are trying a SpaceX type of system then there is a lot more math and physics that needs to be done before giving a definitive answer